# Modifying GDCL MP4 Muxer (Incorrect Header/Footer)

Tags: directshow, mp4

I want to modify GDLC MP4 Muxer  so that

- it will not send data to  other writer but it will just record it
  itself to a file data itself...
- It will be not a muxer any more...it will be a writer which have mp4 muxer...

**But firstly i have to figure out, where is the last [muxed] data stay , so that i can write it to a file...**

To get a playable file, i have to write the data where?

**My Attempts:**

*I put debug info and see that it calls **Append** and  this method call **Replace** periodically...I write the buffer [ BYTE* pBuffer] which is given to Append method of MuxOutput .I get binary data which has some headers but not playable...So it its wrong place or i do it wrong.....Then i check what calls Append --- FillSpace methos and YUVVideoHandler::WriteDescriptor... But can not able to get usefull info from other methods call Append...

**UPDATE**

Well, i can able to write data to file at `MuxOutput::Replace` method...The problem is that the header info and footer(tables at the end of file) are wrong... The other data [ payload data] is correct... The playable file which is recorded by File writer started with  **00 00 00 18**...[hexadecimal] but my recorded data start with **00 00 00 08** [hexadecimal].... when i replace the mp4 header and footer parts with the file generated by the file writer using a hex editor tool, file becomes identical and plays.

**What may be the problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mpeg4Mux::Pause, the MovieWriter is created with a pointer to an AtomWriter interface (in my case, implemented by the output pin by calls to the downstream file-writer filter). All writes to the file are via this interface. The data is written first, and then on stop, the index data (moov chunk) is written and the file header and data chunk headers are updated.

G

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is caused by `Random File Access` requirement which is supported by `File Writer Filter` by default. The steps you need to follow is:

1) Create an empty file at the beginning

```
std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("c:\\out.mp4", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
outFile.close();
```

2) Open file for random access

```
outFile.open("c:\\out.mp4", ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
```

3) Right after output pin's `Write()` method add these lines (replace position, buffer and bufferSize with suitable variable names)

```
outFile.seekp(position);
outFile.write(buffer, bufferSize);
```

4) At the end of the recording session (somewhere like a `Close()` method of the muxer) add

```
outFile.close();
```

And you are done.

Comment: I can not belive my problem cause i so  simple....I failed at seek position of file while wrting it...Thanks...